# i get this error while trying to execute plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
plt.plot(np.arange(100),hr["HourlyRate"]) # scatter plot of single variable
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c1b97ce16e96> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 plt.plot(np.arange(100),hr["HourlyRate"]) # scatter plot of single variable
      3 plt.show()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    340 
    341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (1470,)
```

Comment: You have 1470 records in `HourlyRate`, not 100. Try `hr['HourlyRate'].plot.scatter()`

Comment: if you use `np.arange(100)` for `x` then you should use the same number of values from `hr["HourlyRate"]` - ie. `hr["HourlyRate"][:100]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *hr* is a DataFrame and you want to plot its *HourlyRate* column.

One of possible options is:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(hr.index.size), hr.HourlyRate)
```

This way the number of *x* and *y* values is the same.

Note however a slight change in the way I specified *y* parameter.

- you wrote *hr["HourlyRate"]* which means a **row** with index of
  *HourlyRate*,
- my code refers to a **column** of this name.

Other option is to pass *y* as *hr.loc[:, 'HourlyRate']* (every row
and *HourlyRate* column).